# Undefined index: custom field in locale_field_entity_form_submit() (line 438 of locale module)

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-fields, drupal-field-api

Hi I am getting this kind of error in creating custom node type with custom fields:

> Undefined index: field_block_pre_login_body in locale_field_entity_form_submit() (line 438 of D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\foo\modules\locale\locale.module).

Custom field and custom node type are created thru hook_install:

```
function custom_module_install() {
        $nodeType = new stdClass();
        $nodeType->type = "foo_block";
        $nodeType->orig_type = "foo_block";
        $nodeType->base = "node_content";
        $nodeType->name = "FooBlock";
        $nodeType->description = $t("This is a Custom Content Type for Defining Custom blocks for Pre and Post Login State Functionality on blocks");
        $nodeType->help = "Use This Content Type only if the block will have a Login State requirements";
        $nodeType->custom = TRUE;
        $nodeType->has_title = TRUE;
        $nodeType->title_label = "Custom Block";
        $nodeType->locked = FALSE;
        $nodeType->disabled = FALSE;

        node_type_save($nodeType);
        if (!field_info_field('field_block_pre_login_body')) {
            $field = array(
                'field_name' => $t('field_block_pre_login_body'),
                'type' => 'text_long',
            );
            field_create_field($field);

            // Create the field instance on the bundle.
            $instance = array(
                'field_name' => $t('field_block_pre_login_body'),
                'label' => $t('Pre-Login Body'),
                'bundle' => 'matterhorn_block',
                'entity_type' => 'node',
                'required' => FALSE,
                'widget' => array('type' => 'text_textarea'),
                'settings' => array('text_processing' => 1),
                'format' => 'filter_html',
            );
            field_create_instance($instance);
        }
}
```

Now After I've installed my custom module in Drupal, and add content thru the custom node type I've created, the locale.module prompts an error after creating or updating the content that is created with that content type, any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

** EDIT **

Note: this is drupal module and I need a more detailed explanation as how drupal-field-api works with this because the `field_block_pre_login_body` is created in the index once you've called the `field_create_field` method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this patch:

```
diff --git a/modules/locale/locale.module b/modules/locale/locale.module
    index 768fead..39ae31f 100644
    --- a/modules/locale/locale.module
    +++ b/modules/locale/locale.module
    @@ -434,14 +434,16 @@ function locale_field_entity_form_submit($entity_type, $form, &$form_state ) {

         foreach (field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle) as $instance) {
           $field_name = $instance['field_name'];
    -      $field = field_info_field($field_name);
    -      $previous_language = $form[$field_name]['#language'];
    -
    -      // Handle a possible language change: new language values are inserted,
    -      // previous ones are deleted.
    -      if ($field['translatable'] && $previous_language != $current_language) {
    -        $form_state['values'][$field_name][$current_language] = $entity->{$field_name}[$previous_language];
    -        $form_state['values'][$field_name][$previous_language] = array();
    +      if (!empty($form[$field_name])) {
    +        $field = field_info_field($field_name);
    +        $previous_language = $form[$field_name]['#language'];
    +
    +        // Handle a possible language change: new language values are inserted,
    +        // previous ones are deleted.
    +        if ($field['translatable'] && $previous_language != $current_language) {
    +          $form_state['values'][$field_name][$current_language] = $entity->{$field_name}[$previous_language];
    +          $form_state['values'][$field_name][$previous_language] = array();
    +        }
           }
         }
       }
```

Read more in [Throwing Notice: Undefined index:  in locale_field_entity_form_submit() (line 438 of /path/to/drupal/installation/modules/locale/locale.module).](https://www.drupal.org/node/2356283)